# Noisy Log-Log Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, noise

So I am trying to make a simple log-log plot. However, I get some numerical instabilities and my plot is very noisy:

[image: Plot I am trying to produce]

I have tried using np.float128 in case this was a precision problem which made the plot less noisy but not enough. I think the problem arises from having a very small factor inside the log which becomes negative if we expand it, but I was wondering if there are any solutions to get a smooth plot.

My code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal      

mDM = np.float128(np.logspace(1.0,10.0,10000,True,10.0))
#mDM=np.arange(1.0*10**8, 10**12, 500000)


#Parameters


#B=0.99999
B=0
Edm=np.float128(mDM*(1.0/np.sqrt(1.0-B**2.0)))
print (1.0/np.sqrt(1.0-B**2.0))
v=0.0
A= np.float128(2.5681887353e-27)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
Enu1=np.float128(1.0e3)
x=np.float128(2.0*Edm*Enu1*(1.0 - B*v)/mDM**2.0)
mM=np.float128(np.sqrt(4.0*mDM**2.0 + mDM/(10000000.0*np.sqrt(3.0*A*math.pi)))) 
y=np.float128( (0.01)**4.0*(1.0/(5.06773e4)**2.0)*(mDM**2.0*x**2.0 +  mM**2.0*(1.0 + x)*(np.log(mM**2.0*(1.0 + x)/(mDM**2.0*x**2.0 + mM**2.0*(1.0 + x)))))/(8.0*mDM**2.0*mM**2.0*math.pi*x**2.0)) #(Seems Better)
ax.loglog(mDM,y)
ax.set_xlabel('mDM')
ax.set_ylabel('y')    


plt.show()
fig.savefig("Check.jpeg")
```

Comment: This is just my opinion, but before you concern yourself with making a plot you should study your code to see where the instabilities are coming from.  If you're getting overflows or underflows in your math functions, trying to make a decent plot from the resulting mess is a losing proposition.  BTW one thing that caught my eye was expressions like "25.681887353*10.0**(-28.0)" which is a clumsy way of writing a simple number: "2.5681887353e-27".  If you clean up this sort of thing, it probably won't fix the instabilities but it will make your code easier to read.

Comment: I would guess this is a problem of floating point precision. You may read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). For example the intuitively expected output for `1.e-40 + 0.3 - 3*0.1` is `1e-40`, but it is `-5.5...e-17` (on my 64bit system). Since you have a lot of calculations going on in your script, it's hard to judge at which exact point something like this happens.

Comment: Hi Paul, I know the instability comes from the log term. Not sure what you mean by overflows or underflows. And yes, I am very new to python so I wrote it like that to make sure it was OK but I will take your advice to make it more readable! Thanks
And Ernest, thanks for your tip, that is why I used np.float128. Is there any way to get around this, or to improve the result? Maybe breaking down the calculations? Thanks!

Comment: Independently of this specific problem it is always wise to stay in the analytic domain as long as possible. Try to simplify your problem to a single formula. Sort that formula by constants and variables. Numerically evaluate the constants to give you only few of them. Divide small numbers by large ones, not large ones by small ones. Ans so on and so forth.